# how to create a a bootstrap Carousel with dynamic image source

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, mern

i want to make  a product detail page with  image slider containing all images of a product ,  i have read the directory and got all images of a product now the slider is not moving and only showing the first image :

**here is the code, check the code inside caraousel-inner**

**the files contain array of images names**

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="carousel-inner">


      {files.map(eachFile=>{
          return  <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src={`/products/galleryimages/${product._id}/${eachFile}`} class="d-block img-fluid  w-100 " style={{height:"200px",width:"350px",objectFit:"cover"}} alt="..."/>
    </div>
      })}
 
    
  </div>

  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you first hard code three image with static image url and see if it works.

Comment: @windmaomao yes it worked perfectly , now it only shows the first image in the array

Comment: i think you need to get it working with three hard coded image, not one, if you can't get a static HTML working, then React won't be able to help.

Comment: @windmaomao no i used hard coded image before this but now dynamic values only shows first image the slider does not move to next image

Comment: @windmaomao  i solved it , the   first image in bootstrap carousel  requires it to be active so i check put a ternary operator to check for index and if index is zero then its className is active else not  so it worked

Answer (score 1):

the first image in **bootstrap carousel requires it to be active** so just put a ternary operator **to check for index and if index is zero** then its *className* is **carousel-item active** else **carousel-item**

**code:**

```
{files.map((eachFile,index)=>{
      return  <div  className={index===0?"carousel-item active":"carousel-item "} key={`${eachFile}img`}>
  <img src={`/yourdirectoryPath/${eachFile}`} class="d-block img-fluid  w-100 " style={{height:"200px",width:"350px",objectFit:"cover"}} alt="..."/>
</div>
  })}
```

2: the other problem that you will encounter is that **there are only three buttons indicators** to change image so this means you can not click next to another image  after first three so you have to **create these buttons also dynamically** , here is the complete code !

rememeber the **files** in **files.map** is an array containing images names

**bootstrap-react dynamic carousel  slider**

```
  <div
                      id="carouselExampleIndicators"
                      class="carousel slide"
                      data-bs-ride="carousel"
                    >
                      <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        {files.map((eachFile, index) => {
                          return (
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                              data-bs-slide-to={index}
                              class="active"
                              aria-current="true"
                              aria-label={`Slide ${index + 1}`}
                            ></button>
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>

                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        {files.map((eachFile, index) => {
                          return (
                            <div
                              className={
                                index === 0
                                  ? "carousel-item active"
                                  : "carousel-item "
                              }
                              key={`${eachFile}img`}
                            >
                              <img
                                src={`/youdirectoryPath/${eachFile}`}
                                class="d-block img-fluid  w-100 "
                                style={{
                                  height: "200px",
                                  width: "350px",
                                  objectFit: "cover",
                                }}
                                alt="..."
                              />
                            </div>
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>

                      <button
                        class="carousel-control-prev"
                        type="button"
                        data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="prev"
                      >
                        <span
                          class="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        ></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                      </button>
                      <button
                        class="carousel-control-next"
                        type="button"
                        data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
                        data-bs-slide="next"
                      >
                        <span
                          class="carousel-control-next-icon"
                          aria-hidden="true"
                        ></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
```